# How to migrate drupal6 ubercart to D7 commerce

Tags: commerce, ubercart

I have a website in D6, and ubercart is used now i want to upgrade the site to D7 but with commerce. How can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to look at [Commerce Migrate](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_migrate) together with [Commerce Migrate Übercart](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_migrate_ubercart) that respectively understand how to create Commerce content and read Übercart content.

Commerce Guys already wrote two blogposts, [Part 1](http://commerceguys.com/blog/ubercart-drupal-commerce-pt-1), and [Part 2](http://commerceguys.com/blog/ubercart-drupal-commerce-pt-2), on the difference between the two.